# Unfortunately (App Name) Has Stopped Working?

Tags: java, android

I am new to Java, and, particularly, Android Development. I have a menu and two other items work on the menu (MainActivity, and a Splash Screen), but when I run this class, Gentile, from the menu the App crashes:

```
public class Gentile extends Activity {

    Random rand = new Random();
    Button ranNumBut;
    int ranNum = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;
    TextView display2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ranNumBut= (Button) findViewById(R.id.rand);
        display2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay2);

        ranNumBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                display2.setText("ranNum");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);` missing

after `super.onCreate()` and before finding any views

Answer (score 0):

Your app is crashing because ranNumBut is null. In the future, please look at your device's log (accessible with the "adb logcat" terminal command) and include the relevant exception that caused the crash in your question.  Consider looking at the Android tutorials on developer.android.com to get a better idea of how to get started programming for Android.